# ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it. when testing a model with a NULLABLE image field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing

I'm testing a `model` called `Category` that looks like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

As you can see the `image` field is **nullable** but when I try to create a `Category` instance in my `TestCase` Im getting the following error:

```
raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Here's the test:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.category = Category.objects.create(title='test_category')
```

I already tried creating it like this:

```
Category.objects.create(title='test_category', image=Null)
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a template error since I didn't handle the possibility of a **category** not having an image and when I ran the test on a `CategoryListView` it returned an error because the *test* category had no **image**.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, this should work

```
class Category(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)



def setUp(self):
    self.category = Category(title='test_category')
    self.category.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already fixed it :)